# How to show emailid in Email input field whenever emailid get clicked using reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react, my objective is to show email id in email component under `email` input field. I mean when we click on email id then it should go to email component and the emailid should appear under `email` input field. How to reuse the email component while clicking on the email id's everytime. for example: normal way when we click on any emailid automatically it will go to our gmail compose with the respective emailid to write an email. in the same way, here when i click on emailid then it should redirect to Email component with the respective emailid in input field.

Here is the code:

```
<Segment>
          {Data.map(view => {
            return (
              <Table>
                <Table.Header>
                  <Table.Row>
                    <Table.HeaderCell>firstName</Table.HeaderCell>
                    <Table.HeaderCell>Email</Table.HeaderCell>
                    <Table.HeaderCell>Applied On</Table.HeaderCell>
                  </Table.Row>
                </Table.Header>

                <Table.Body key={view.Id}>
                  <Table.Row>
                    <Table.Cell>First Name</Table.Cell>
                    <Table.Cell>
                      <Link to="/Email">{view.email}</Link>
                    </Table.Cell>
                    <Table.Cell>{view.date}</Table.Cell>
                  </Table.Row>
                </Table.Body>
              </Table>
            );
          })}
        </Segment>
```

Can anyone help me in this query?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Link` tags are imported from `react-router`,

---

```
 <Link to={{ pathname: "/Email", state: { id: view.Id } }}>{view.email}</Link>
```

---

Now just wrap your `Email` component with `withRouter`

---

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

function Email(props) {
  console.log( props.location && props.location.state &&props.location.state.id )
 ...rest code...
} 
export default withRouter(Email)
```

---

For making `props.location.state.id` holds the id at `Email component

Comment: Hi, Still i couldn't get the emailid in email component

Comment: Where do i need to give `props.location.state.id`. Could you please help me

Comment: Editing my answer

Comment: Still not getting the email id :(

Comment: Hi  Sandhya, Link with state object is the way to pass data to next page. Incase you have doubts, check the codesandbox link.

https://codesandbox.io/s/a-simple-react-router-v4tutorial-9s70l?file=/components/App.js